# Which of the following functions are harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I was going through my textbook in Complex Analysis and I found the following exercise:

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $f=u+iv$ be a holomorphic function
> on $D$. Which of the following functions are harmonic?
>
> (a) $a=\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$
>
> (b) $b=\dfrac{u}{u^2+v^2}$
>
> (c) $c=\dfrac{u-v}{u^2+v^2}$

I know that a function $h$ is harmonic if and only if there is a holomorphic function $g$ such that $\text{Re} \ g = h$ (or at least this holds locally). This means that $u$ is harmonic, i.e. $\Delta u = 0$. Firstly, I tried to calculate the Laplacian of these functions ($\Delta a, \Delta b, \Delta c$) but these calculations turn out pretty ugly. So instead I tried to find holomorphic functions $g_a, g_b, g_c$ such that $\text{Re} \ g_a = a, \text{Re} \ g_b = b, \text{Re} \ g_c = c$ holds.

It's easy to note that $a = \text{Re} \dfrac{f}{|f|}$. Now,
$$ \frac{f}{|f|} = \frac{f}{\sqrt{f \overline{f}}} = \sqrt{\frac{f}{\overline{f}}} $$

Similarly, we have $ b = \text{Re}\dfrac{f}{|f|^2}$, and
$$ \frac{f}{|f|^2} = \frac{f}{f\overline{f}} = \frac{1}{\overline{f}}$$
or $c = \text{Re} \dfrac{f+if}{|f|^2}$, and
$$ \frac{(1+i)f}{|f|^2} = \frac{(1+i)f}{f\overline{f}} = \frac{1+i}{\overline{f}},$$
but I'm not sure how to decide whether these functions are holomorphic or not...

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f\in\mathcal{H}(D)$ with $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ then by the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have  $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ then $u$ is harmonic function and $v$ too.

Comment: *Hint:* $\frac 1f =\frac{u-iv}{u^2+v^2}$ ...

Comment: Ok, so $b = \text{Re} \dfrac{1}{f}$, but why is that holomorphic? It's derivative would be $-\dfrac{f'}{f^2}$, but what if for some $z\in D$ we have $f(z) = 0$?

Comment: @sicmath: $1/f$ is holomorphic wherever it is defined, and then its real part is harmonic.